# Angular-Fullstack get current user

Tags: javascript, angularjs, yeoman, angular-fullstack

I'm not able to get the current user ID in the controller. I have this:

**controller.js:**

```
constructor(Auth) {
    this.getCurrentUser = Auth.getCurrentUserSync;
    // console.log(this.getCurrentUser()._id) returns undefined
  }
```

But, if I print in the html:

```
p {{ctrl.getCurrentUser()._id}}
```

I get perfectly the user ID.

Why is this happening?? How can I get the user ID in the controller?

**EDIT:**

The `Auth.getCurrentUser()` function looks like:

```
function getCurrentUser(callback) {
          var value = _.get(currentUser, '$promise') ? currentUser.$promise : currentUser;

          return $q.when(value).then(function (user) {
            safeCb(callback)(user);
            return user;
          }, function () {
            safeCb(callback)({});
            return {};
          });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just access like,

```
console.log($$state.value.data._id);
```

**DEMO**

```js
var userinfo = { $$state: {
   status: 1,
    value: {              
          data: {
           __v: 0,
          _id: "596b33283055cd0f2442cd85"               
           }               
         }
    } 
}

console.log(userinfo.$$state.value.data._id);
```

Comment: But is it that the best way to get the current user id?? I thought it could be easier...

Comment: Sorry, accessing like that I get `Error: userinfo.$$state.value is undefined`. I mean, Angular-Fullstack provides you the getCurrentUser function, it's supposed to return easily the user data, isn't it? Don't know how it really works...

Comment: If I print `userinfo.$$state` it returns `Object { status: 0 }` instead... :/

Comment: tats the issue, it does not have the id